# How do I apply my python code to all of the files in a folder at once, and how do I create a new name for each subsequent output file?

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, naming, pypdf

The code I am working with takes in a .pdf file, and outputs a .txt file. My question is, how do I create a loop (probably a for loop) which runs the code over and over again on all files in a folder which end in ".pdf"? Furthermore, how do I change the output each time the loop runs so that I can write a new file each time, that has the same name as the input file (ie. 1_pet.pdf > 1_pet.txt, 2_pet.pdf > 2_pet.txt, etc.)

Here is the code so far:

```
path="2_pet.pdf"
content = getPDFContent(path)
encoded = content.encode("utf-8")
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(encoded)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all files in directory with extension .txt with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that encapsulates what you want to do to each file.

```
import os.path

def parse_pdf(filename):
    "Parse a pdf into text"
    content = getPDFContent(filename)
    encoded = content.encode("utf-8")
    ## split of the pdf extension to add .txt instead.
    (root, _) = os.path.splitext(filename)
    text_file = open(root + ".txt", "w")
    text_file.write(encoded)
    text_file.close()
```

Then apply this function to a list of filenames, like so:

```
for f in files:
    parse_pdf(f)
```

Comment: This looks like it will work! The problem is that I need files to refer to my directory. Would I do it like this?

`files = "Users/Jack/Downloads/pyPdf-1.13"`

Comment: You can get the files from a directory using glob, like in Rob's answer

Comment: That helped, and actually worked (kind of). I now am having the issue that the named text files are being returned, but they are blank, and when I try to do a few hundred files, I get the error `pyPdf.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found`. Do you have any idea why either of these are happening? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: check that `content.encode` is not returning `None`: I think it might change the encoding "in place". Try adding `print encoded` for example, to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover all the aspect of the OP question i.e.  "on all files in a the folder".

Answer (score 5):

The following script solve your problem:

```
import os

sourcedir = 'pdfdir'

dl = os.listdir('pdfdir')

for f in dl:
    fs = f.split(".")
    if fs[1] == "pdf":
        path_in = os.path.join(dl,f)
        content = getPDFContent(path_in)
        encoded = content.encode("utf-8")
        path_out = os.path.join(dl,fs[0] + ".txt")
        text_file = open(path_out, 'w')
        text_file.write(encoded)
        text_file.close()
```

Comment: This returned the following error for me:

    `dl = os.dirlist("Users/Jack/Downloads/pyPdf-1.13")
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dirlist'`

Comment: Sorry, listdir not dirlist, my mistake, I corrigated.

Comment: Note, that this code solves the directory seeking too in contrast with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to operate on all PDF files in a directory is to invoke `glob.glob()` and iterate over the results:

```
import glob
for path in glob.glob('*.pdf')
    content = getPDFContent(path)
    encoded = content.encode("utf-8")
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(encoded)
    text_file.close()
```

Another way is to allow the user to specify the files:

```
import sys
for path in sys.argv[1:]:
    ...
```

Then the user runs your script like `python foo.py *.pdf`.

Comment: I just added this to my code, and it ran without returning any errors, however my output file only relates to my first pdf file. Is there a reason why it might not be running past the first file?

Also, how do I go about changing the output during each iteration of the for loop to mirror the file name of the pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function to search the folders and all subfolders for files that end with pdf. Than take those files and then create a text file for it.

It could be something like:

```
import os

def convert_PDF(path, func):
    d = os.path.basename(path)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        [convert_PDF(os.path.join(path,x), func) for x in os.listdir(path)]
    elif d[-4:] == '.pdf':
        funct(path)

# based entirely on your example code
def convert_to_txt(path):
    content = getPDFContent(path)
    encoded = content.encode("utf-8")
    file_path = os.path.dirname(path)
    # replace pdf with txt extension
    file_name = os.path.basename(path)[:-4]+'.txt'
    text_file = open(file_path +'/'+file_name, "w")
    text_file.write(encoded)
    text_file.close()

convert_PDF('path/to/files', convert_to_txt)
```

Because the actual operation is changeable, you can replace the function with whatever operation you need to perform (like using a different library, converting to a different type, etc.)